# RTMP stream with adobe flash player

Tags: flash, video-streaming, rtmp

I use NGINX for web server. Can you tell me about the role of flash player in rtmp streaming video on demand, especially synchronize audio and video ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Tell me about the role of flash player in rtmp streaming video on
>   demand...*

RTMP and Flash are both made by Adobe.

Flash Player is a browser plugin to run (inside a webpage) applications made with Adobe's own AS3 programming language. It's like an operating system that runs (or "plays") Flash applications.

RTMP is a system of sending live audio/video. It can be used for broadcasting online radio streams, on-demand or live video streams (eg: sports, movies, etc).

On the web, RTMP is only decoded through Flash Plugin, so you must make (or find) a media-playback application coded in AS3. It will be compiled as `.swf` file and you embed this `.swf` within an html file by using the `<embed>` tag.

The Flash `.swf` application uses code to load the RTMP data and the Flash Player system will automatically decode that into live audio/video. Just like the browser decodes some `.mp4` video when your code loads a file within a `<video>` tag.

Comment: thanks you very much, can you give me some documents which have detail infomation about Flash Player transmission session ?